# Como remover todos os arquivos de uma pasta?

Tags: android, apache-cordova

Estou tentando remover todos os arquivos de uma pasta usando Cordova e Android, o problema é que todo código que eu acho, só mostra como remover ARQUIVOS e não ARQUIVOS DE UMA PASTA.

O problema é que não sei o nome dos arquivos.

Segue um exemplo de código para remover arquivos (preciso remover ARQUIVOS dos quais não sei o nome de uma pasta)

```
var path =  cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory;
var filename = "arquivoABC.txt";

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, function(dir) {
    dir.getFile(filename, {create:false}, function(fileEntry) {
              fileEntry.remove(function(){
                  // The file has been removed succesfully
              },function(error){
                  // Error deleting the file
              },function(){
                 // The file doesn't exist
              });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve usar o método `removeRecursively()`. Por exemplo:

```
$cordovaFile.removeRecursively('/storage/sdcard/meudiretorio', "")
  .then(function (success) {
    // apagou com sucesso

}, function (error) {
    // erro ao apagar arquivos
});
```

Métodos básicos se tratando de arquivo no Apache Cordova:

- `removeRecursively`: Excluir um diretório e todo o seu conteúdo.
- `getMetadata`: Procurar os metadados de um diretório.
- `setMetadata`: Definir metadados em um diretório.
- `moveTo`: Mover um diretório para um local diferente no sistema de arquivos
- `copyTo`: Copiar um diretório para um local diferente no sistema de arquivos
- `toURL`: Retornar um URL que pode ser usado para localizar um diretório.
- `remove`: Excluir um diretório. O diretório deve estar vazio.
- `getParent`: Procurar o diretório pai
- `createReader`: Criar um novo `DirectoryReader` que pode ler entradas de um diretório.
- `getDirectory`: Criar ou procurar um diretório.
- `getFile`: Criar ou procurar um arquivo.

Veja mais detalhes [**na documentação**](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/).

Comment: Não existe esse $cordovaFile no meu app.

Comment: @PauloHDSousa No seu caso em vez de ser `dir.getFile` seria `dir.removeRecursively`.

Comment: Resolvi de uma maneira um pouco diferente,  o removeRecursively não funcionou, mas fiz algo parecido, segue.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi de uma maneira parecida do **removeRecursively**

Tive a ideia graças ao amigo Ack Lay, obrigado.

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onRequestFileSystem, fail);

            function onRequestFileSystem(fileSystem) {
                var directoryReader = fileSystem.root.createReader();
                directoryReader.readEntries(onReadEntries, fail);
            }

            function onReadEntries(entries) {
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                    if (entries[i].name.indexOf("pacoteapp_v") !== -1) {
                        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(entries[i].nativeURL, function (dir) {
                            dir.getFile(entries[i].name, { create: false }, function (fileEntry) {
                                fileEntry.remove(function () {
                                }, function (error) {
                                }, function () {
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Na verdade o `removeRecursively()` faz isso que você fez porém recursivamente, que na teoria é muito mais eficiente.

Comment: @AckLay o problema é que eu salvo os arquivos na raiz do storage, e acabaria deletando outros que não fazem parte do app

Comment: O correto mesmo então, seria você criar um diretório específico e colocar seus arquivos lá para não acontecer esse tipo de problema. Tem que tomar cuidado, pois o que não é trabalhoso pra você agora, futuramente pode dar uma dor de cabeça.

Comment: O problema é que já está rodando deste modo, o que posso fazer é salvar os futuros arquivos em uma pasta separada como você disse.

Comment: Fica a seu critério melhorar a qualidade do seu código para não ter problemas futuros (como esse agora). Enfim, boa sorte ae! =)

Comment: @AckLay Vou fazer isso então, muito obrigado pelas dicas.